# Python on Windows - Issue with getting correct process id when opening file explorer programmatically

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pid, explorer

I need to open the file explorer window programmatically and hold the pid of the process, to use it later to close the file explorer window

```
import os, subprocess

#Open file explorer
p = subprocess.Popen(['explorer.exe'])

#Close file explorer
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

When executing this, I get an error `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`
Also when checking in task manager, I don’t see any process running with the pid value of p.pid

The same code works fine, when trying with another exe.

```
import os, subprocess

#Open file explorer
p = subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe'])

#Close file explorer
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

And this time, I see the notepad.exe is running with the pid as shown by p.pid

Issue seems to be specific to executing explorer.exe. Can someone throw some light on what’s special about explorer.exe in windows.

The no. of times explorer.exe is executed is not proportional to the no of processes shown in the task manager

Comment: Running a program can activate an already running instance and then exit, as is often the case with explorer.exe. Just because you see a new window, that doesn't mean the window belongs to the process that you created. Use `p.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)`, which in Windows calls `p.terminate()`, which calls `_winapi.TerminateProcess(p._handle, 1)`. This internally handles the `PermissionError` if the process already exited. (`p._handle` is a reliable handle for the kernel process object. The PID is not, though modern versions of Windows are better about not reusing PIDs.)

Comment: Though p.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM) does not help solve this fully, it does not atleast throw the permission error. None of these p.terminate(), p.kill(), p._handle.Close() closes the opened explorer.